# find probabilities involving a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

The number $X$ of calls to a mental health support line has been identified as following a Poisson distribution with a rate of $10$ per hour.

> Find the probability of $3$ calls in one hour **AND** $6$ in the next hour, stating the assumption you are making in this calculation.

I found the $$P(3 \text{ calls})=\frac{^}{x!} e^{(−)}(e)^{(-)},$$

$P(x=3)=0.00757$. But how do I figure out the probability of $6$ calls in the next hour so I can multiply them?

I'm assuming that events occur singly, and the probability of two events occurring simultaneously is zero.

Comment: What do you know about the number of calls in disjoint intervals?

Comment: "poison distribution" : dangerous question...

Comment: I don't much about that? I still have not been taught bivariate distributions

Comment: The probability of $6$ calls in an hour is $P(X=6)$

Comment: why do we do this? if we calc p(x=6) then do we calc P(x=3andx=6) and so do we assume that Poisson distribution is independent because is memoryless

Comment: Your title is still "poison"ous...